# Is it possible to apply formatters only for selected lines using ALE Vim plugin?

Tags: formatting, plugin-ale

I want to format only a part of file and keep the rest unchanged using [ALE](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale). I imagine that its kinda possible by providing a fragment of code for example for `black` formatter and replacing the selected lines with the result retrieved from `black`.

Applying formatter for a large file could cause too many changes. Its way easier to track what have changed if only a part of the file is changed at once.

Comment: How would ALE know which part of the file to operate on? Setting `formatprg` is probably a better option, I think? But you need to invoke that manually.

Comment: @MartinTournoij I imagine that visual-line mode could be used to select the block for the formatting.

Comment: Yeah, you could use `formatprg` for that, assuming that `black` can operate on partial files: `set formatprg=black` (may need flags?), select what you want to be formatted, and then `gq`. Many people like to map `gq` to `q` btw, which is a bit easier to type.

Comment: @MartinTournoij i use `Q`, perhaps that’s what you meant? Black does have some issues when the partial file is not syntactically correct, and it’s also noisy (needs some cleanup). And i think a stdin or - flag is required

Answer (score 2):

Range formatting is not supported by black because range of lines are in general not valid Python code.

You may have a look at `black-macchiato`.

Install `black-macchiato` by running the shell command:

```
pip install black-macchiato
```

To format a range of select lines run the vim command:

```
:'<,'>!python -m macchiato
```

You can also set the corresponding `formatprg` command.

```
:setlocal formatprg=python -m macchiato
```

This will allow you to format using the `gq` command.

You can also install the pluging `smbl64/vim-black-macchiato`: [vim-black-macchiato](https://github.com/smbl64/vim-black-macchiato)

Remark: Black-Macchiato doesn't work out of the box on Windows but there are two forks that solve the problem on Windows, *e.g.*, [black-macchiato](https://github.com/vds2212/black-macchiato).

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this now with vim9script in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`:

```
autocmd! BufWritePre <buffer> {
  var view = winsaveview()
  silent! execute ':%!black --quiet -'
  winrestview(view)
}
```

To automatically format python filetype buffers just before saving.

To use the `gq` operator, you can set also do `setlocal formatprg=black\ --quiet\ -` but beware this will not always work, for example if you select a line like `def add(a                    b)` black can't parse that and you'll get the black error put in your buffer, however, if you select the entire function, let's say it's:

```
def add(a               b):
    answer       = a     + b
    return answer
```

and you do `gqap` on it, this will work, or if you did `vip` then `gq`, that works as well.